# BoxV2 .Net API RefreshAccessTokenAsync() method throws Object reference Error

Tags: box-api, boxapiv2

I am using **BoxV2** .Net SDK. When I attempt refresh AcccessToken, I get an **Object reference not set to an instance of an object** error. There is no inner exception details. Below line of code is throwing error. Can anyone advice what is wrong with the call?

```
await client.Auth.RefreshAccessTokenAsync("my-refresh-token");
```

Below is the code snippet wihch I use to get the tokens first time.

```
var config = new BoxConfig("client-id", "client-secret", new Uri("return-url"));
var client = new BoxClient(config);
```

Making a request to `config.AuthCodeUri.ToString()` to get the **one-time-code** for authentication

```
OAuthSession session = await client.Auth.AuthenticateAsync("one-time-code"); 
string refreshToken = session.RefreshToken;
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. The **BoxClient** requires a valid **OAuthSession** to function properly. So I had to use the overloaded constructor of BoxClient which accepts OAuthSession session parameter. So I modified the code as below and it worked flawlessly.

```
var session = new OAuthSession("access-token", "refresh-token", "expires-in", "token-type");
var config = new BoxConfig("client-id", "client-secret", new Uri("return-url"));
var client = new BoxClient(config, session);
```